# Using numpy data types in argparse

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, user-input, argparse

I am setting up a Argparse parser to read some user input through the shell. The input will be used to extract data from a pandas DataFrame containing strings and numbers. I want to automatically set the `type=` argument in Argparse`.add_argument()` to match the datatype of the respective column.

My idea was to set up the Argparse arguments like this, where *inputdata* is the DataFrame:

```
for c in inputdata.columns:
        inputname= c
        inputtype= np.dtype(inputdata[c])
        parser.add_argument("--"+inputname, type=inputtype)
```

However, this does not work: Python raises a `ValueError: dtype('int64') is not callable` . I figure this is because I'm not feeding it the Numpy filetypes right; if I e.g. set inputtype to *float*, all goes according to plan. If I manually enter `type=np.int64`, Argparse has no problem with this either.

- How can I get it to accept the filetypes in my DataFrame, namely *int64* and *object* in the loop shown above? I tried some of the options [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) as well, e.g. `dtype.type` but nothing worked.
- Or is this just not possible? The Argparse [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) state only that

> Common built-in types and functions can be used directly as the value of the type argument

but as I said above it seems fine with numpy datatype if put in explicitly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In this context `callable` is usually a function that takes a string (from your input) and converts it to something else.  And raises an error is the input string is ill formed.  `np.int64('123')` works.  `np.dtype('int64')('123')` does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
inputtype = np.dtype(inputdata[c]).type
```

or

```
inputtype = inputdata[c].dtype.type
```

The `.type` attribute is callable, and can be used to create new instances of that dtype.